# Finding Differences in Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formatting

I have a spreadsheet with one column of employee names and another of job titles.

I am trying to find values in the job title column that are different if the value in name category is the same. For example if J. Smith was listed twice but once with a tile of Technician III and another time with a title of Technician both titles would be highlighted (or some other flag to draw me to the difference.)

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and easiest way to do this would be to add a third column that 'flags' the inconsistencies.

Assuming the names like 'J Smith' were in column A, and the titles were in column B, the following formula could be placed into cell C2 and dragged down.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"&B2)>0,"This name has multiple titles","")
```

Comment: you could also use conditional formatting - highlighting all duplicates in names col, then filter by highlight - so you would have all troublesome lines. Beacause as I understand it, you want to delete the wrong duplicates in your list.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use conditional formatting to solve this. Beacause as I understand it, you want to make it easier for your self to delete the *wrong* duplicates.

Using the 'duplicates' preset to highlight all duplicates in the *names* column, then filter your Data by highlight of this column, so you would have all troublesome lines.